# Equivalent resistance for an infinite ladder with resistances in arithmetic progression

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

I tried writing equivalent resistance as a functional equation of x with x as the lower limit, but couldn't proceed further.
Is there a better way to approach the question?

$$\frac{(x+1)f(x+2)}{(x+1)+f(x+2)} + x = f(x)$$

Comment: Use Kirchoff's voltage law for the infinite series of loops create by thinking of the current loop going from A to B through each of the vertical resistors.  I.e. V = I1 * ( 1 + 2 ), V = I2 * ( 1 + 3 + 4 ), ...

Answer (score 0):

You could also express it as an infinite sum running over n where n is the number of "blocks" each consisting of one series and one parallel resistor. Then, if you wave your hands and stare long enough at the sum it will transform before your eyes into an integral, at which time you reach for the math handbook and enjoy a big cup of coffee.

HINT: this is how the *distributed impedance* of a radio frequency transmission line is derived from an infinite series of *lumped elements*.

Comment: I tried to do so, but I am not able to get the function in that approach